# C# , RSAC , pem file ,RSA

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I have keys which were generated in openssl and I need to generate the key signature  like ".pem. file from another key which will encrypt my text. I don't want to get it in XML.  it is RSAC

### for example  the result in xml is like that  .

```
<RSAKeyValue>
 <Modulus>xSFUXcDCAJJ3v3J87W7w92OuZ7JKuVv4Jpv0wkudbNKzd61HQPvbddq2dHWSxdjtbnqCbSiqnft5+BfuY4A81v4ZukIxwPza70jgGCb0dLToePteQdaUDxAoJToO5IqfkfeqinKuYKaGT35CrWzr27GQqWYc7QeuQkrJ6EHdJ3E=</Modulus>
  <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
  <P>4+Y3AWv5yta+Pe4VfDWAyZrBuY09ZZUAtqEu/DLvQF6F3DECh2JZM7eVff03Ffiw2TdYYvAnuuQicTCcMkVwPw==</P>
  <Q>3W/ee5qV12ayXLL1D/UCbWBQLEKp/vgicc9DtunVNT/5wdfMP1WZTW/csbiVmBKzc48olC9QFbZ8AzHEX698Tw==</Q>
  <DP>AL6Bs3l8yVLGMEGUxGEQWJguxcJWTvybkf0YwC4SZe1pFnz6eyKxE+Anls+63FGBklQB7+DE4HFaQ3BbMjbT1Q==</DP>
  <DQ>vBvBWy0Z5071a+wWZETVmAa+dKr48IDn+diBhIwls8OyLqpcdt0HixHg4BSW+AXC7gMKDMAYfylzNd98G3De3w==</DQ>
  <InverseQ>THgQutS7iiFQ0jDRroujpA5DfSfkQu8amv6bYD56zg61f4adm4zf6nTDOrut3i7GXxdKK+7PoRcbXdXmq6wO9Q==</InverseQ>
  <D>KT6f+D2sWZJLm7LIkKT1pc0lYGzdVYr4kJtwynYnqe0rv45xqhcIA9CO/C7dVqfchZD8WPp5ODS1gEMBja/3CmZ8SK04LEtZSHgMmTwZpH1Efpzz+9h/ujvxI1k4r521a7F1NV71YHZRMtyMfTlynYhpA6y1OyEa6tyhLLKRVEE=</D>
</RSAKeyValue>  

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
the file that i have is  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

---

please how i can slove this problem . anyone who can i need your soggestions .

Comment: I find your question very confusing: could you please be more specific about what you have, what you want and what tools you are using?

Comment: ok  . problem is that  . i have the keys  in format .pem    which i get from openssl in linux  .  now i want to generate the keys in format .pem  also read the key in format  .pem  . but in C# using RSACriptoProvider i couldnot  do this  . in other words i want to do the work what openssl did  .